# python searching allflicks (a website) to see if a show is on netflix

Tags: python, automation, web-scraping

I want to sharpen my python skills and build a program that would use http://www.allflicks.net/ to search for a given title and return if it is available on netflix. Since netflix has removed access to their public api I need to figure out how to search for the show inside allflicks and return the results. The issue I'm having is the way allflicks works is as the name of the show is being typed a list is being narrowed based on the input.

The examples I've seen on here and other websites assume the websites search box will automatically take you to the results once you fill the search box and do .click, but this isn't working for me. Any ideas on a specific library I might need, or any general advice would be extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: hi msaldivar, how were you able to get the data ?? i can see the long url in console but it won't work in php curl request or even in any other way. could you guide me how u did it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to intercept the requests your browser is making so that you can view them. There should be a request that searches for the movies based on the name. You can then use `urllib` or a package like `requests` to make the same request from inside Python. You can then interpret this request to determine whether or not the movie is on Netflix.

You may want to look into an intercepting proxy or a browser addon that will allow you to take a look at the requests and responses for your browser.

In firefox you can use Tamper Data, an add on that lets you capture outgoing requests.

A quick peak at allflicks.com shows me that a request is sent out every time you type into the search box. The response is labelled as text/html, but it appears to actually be JSON. Each request has a ton of query parameters on it, but the important one is `search_value` or something similarly named.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!! I installed tamper data and was able to see all the data, and it became easy after that.

Comment: Hi skyler , i tried the same but wasn't agle to get it. i used firbug , it shows me long request url which return data. when i hit the url in firefox it returns json but nothing in chrome and same happens when implement it using php any lead ??

Comment: @ankushmadaan I am not sure I understand your issue. If you are getting a different response when loading the website based on the browser, then the website is likely responding based on some difference in header values. In particular, your User-Agent will be different with chrome than with firefox.

Comment: @skyler , got that working on both browsers but not in php. I used curl request with setting user agent and everything i could try but i get a blank response with a successful request.

Comment: There are other headers that could result in a different response. You might want to try setting cookies and setting the referer field.

Answer (score 0):

Hello so I wrote some code for this exact thing as a lot of websites gave for USA or other regions and couldnt translate to the exact answer that worked for my netflix. 
https://github.com/Eglis05/netflix-selenium 
You can have a look at it and report anything you dont like. :) 
Most of the code I copy-pasted below.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get(URL)
try:
    username_field = browser.find_element_by_id("id_userLoginId")
    username_field.send_keys(USERNAME)
    password_field = browser.find_element_by_id("id_password")
    password_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)

except:
    username_field = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
    username_field.send_keys(USERNAME)
    password_field = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
    password_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)
login_button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('login-button')
login_button.click()
time.sleep(2)
profile_button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('profile-icon')
profile_button.click()
search_box = browser.find_element_by_class_name('searchTab')
search_box.click()
search_box = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[placeholder='Titles, people, genres']")
```

And lets say the movie you want to search is saved in variable movie

```
search_box.send_keys(movie)
time.sleep(1)
names = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('slider-refocus')
```

You might want to check for 1-4 first movies that show up. You save that number in the variable nr_checkings:

```
for i in range(nr_checkings):
    name = names[2 * i + 1].get_attribute('aria-label')
    if movie == name:
        return True
return False
```

Comment: Please paste the physical code in your question instead of putting a link.

Comment: It it like a rule or something for that ?

Comment: It says here that it is too long and I cant copy paste it.

Comment: Well, try to paste some relevant parts at least.